# How do I modify the XML file of a property (Android Studio)

Tags: android, xml

I have this code:

```
    private Properties properties;
    private static final String myFile = "properties.xml";

 // code for properties
    File file = new File(getFilesDir(), myFile);
    properties = new Properties();

    try{

        if(file.exists()){

            FileInputStream fish = openFileInput(myFile);
            properties.loadFromXML(fis);
            fis.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, "LOADED FROM STORAGE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {

            FileOutputStream fosa = openFileOutput(myFile, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            properties.storeToXML(fos, null);
            fos.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, "CREATED THE FILE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.wtf("MAIN", "error loading file");
    }
```

And I want to enter the xml file that the property generate, but it doen't appear in the Android studio project, does anyone know where do I can find it, or how to modify it by code?

Comment: It is in [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) of the device or emulator that you ran your code on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for `saveName()` & `menuActivity()`:

```
public void saveName(View view){

    properties.setProperty("name", this.editText.getText().toString());

    try{
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(myFile, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        properties.storeToXML(fos, null);
        fos.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.wtf("MAIN", "fail loading file");
    }
    this.textView4.setText(properties.getProperty("name"));
}

public void menuActivity(View v){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MenuActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, MENU_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```